# Count freq of multiple raster objects in R

Tags: r, r-raster

I want to write a df with the freq of 150 raster objects.

I know I can read individual raster objects with

```
raster_x <- raster::raster()
```

I can further get the freq with

```
raster_freq_y <- raster::freq(raster_x)
```

After that I can bind the freq outputs of multiple raster objects to a df with

```
cbind.data.frame(raster_freq_x, raster_freq_y)
```

What I dont know is how to do this for 150 raster objects in one go?

Should I use a loop? If so what kind of loop would make sense?

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the `RasterLayer` objects have the same extent and resolution, you can combine them in a `RasterStack`. The below example is from `?freq`

Example data:

```
library(raster)
r <- raster(nrow=18, ncol=36)
r[] <- runif(ncell(r))
r[1:5] <- NA
s <- stack(r, r*2, r*3)
```

Solution:

```
freq(s, merge=TRUE)
```

If the `RasterLayer` objects do *not* have the same extent and resolution, you can keep them together in a list and use `lapply`

```
ss <- list(r, r*2, r*3)
lapply(ss, freq)
```

Comment: They dont have the same extent but the same resolution. Creating a list with ```spatial.tools::list.raster.files()``` and then calling ```lapply(ls$raster,freq)``` did the trick. I really have to learn more about lapply.Thank you so much!

Comment: Maybe you can help with the second part of the question as well? <https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52388444/how-can-i-write-parts-of-a-list-into-one-data-frame>