# How can I write parts of a list into one data frame?

Tags: r, list, loops, r-raster

I want to write a single df with the freq of 150 raster objects
(partly answered in:
[Count freq of multiple raster objects in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52365579/count-freq-of-multiple-raster-objects-in-r))

I have created a list of all the raster files with

`spatial.tools::list.raster.files()` 
and then called

`lapply(ls$raster,freq)`

Now I have a list containing 150 entries that contain a freq matrix for every raster file.

I am only interested in `$Band.1[,"count"])` however. 
For a single entry of the list I can create a df for counts with

```
as.data.frame(all[[1]]$Band.1[,"count"])
```

My question is: 
How can I write `$Band.1[,"count"]` for all of the 150 in the list into a single df in one go???

Answer (score 0):

I see you're new here. Others will have an easier time answering your question if you can make your question reproducible -- check out this post on [how to make a great reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269/2572423). That being said, using your other question, this should likely get you what you need:

```
library(tidyverse)

list_of_results <- lapply(ls$raster,freq)

df_of_results <- 
  list_of_results %>%
  map_df(~ data.frame(.))

df_of_results$count
```

If the `tidyverse` and `purrr::map` functions aren't your thing, you could also do something like:

```
results <- unlist(lapply(list_of_results, function(x) x[, c("count")]))
```

Comment: You're right im new here. Thanks for the advice I'll try to incorporate it.
```df_of_results <- 
  list_of_results %>%
  map_df(~ data.frame(.))```
is working just fine. 
```results <- unlist(lapply(list_of_results, function(x) x[, c("count")]))```
throws this error: "Error in x[, c("count")] : incorrect number of dimensions"

Comment: Another problem is that the ouput of the first solution is a data frame with a single column for four different values.. Does the ```purr::map```function offer a way to make it 4 columns instead of a single one?

Comment: @loening I think for all of these questions, it would really be easier for others to help you with a reproducible example. Use fake/dummy data to illustrate your problem, what you've tried, and what you expect the output to look like.